# jupyter notebook not opening in Azure ML studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-openai

Is there something wrong with this file - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-OpenAI-Docs-Samples/blob/main/Samples/Tutorials/Embeddings/embedding_billsum.ipynb

When I download it and try to open it in `azure ml studio`, I get error `Rendering failed with error: Content of the ipynb file is not valid jupyter notebook JSON.`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to download the notebook you referred to and load it on Azure Machine Learning:
[image: AML working notebook]

Please, take a look on the version you've downloaded to check if it looks like this:

- Correct json notebook structure:

```html
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "id": "4e082724-c77a-4188-889a-fb5eb028d298",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
...
```

- Incorrect HTML downloaded from Github:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-color-mode="auto" data-light-theme="light" data-dark-theme="dark" data-a11y-animated-images="system">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github.githubassets.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://github.githubassets.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com">
...
```

This incorrect format usually happens if you right-click the link and select the "Save Link as" option. As an alternative, on Chrome, go to the [raw version of the file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-OpenAI-Docs-Samples/main/Samples/Tutorials/Embeddings/embedding_billsum.ipynb), right-click and select "Save as", keeping the extension ipynb. Then, in AML, it should work.